# why non-blocking write to disk doesn't return EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, nonblocking, system-calls

I modified a program from APUE, the program first open a file, then mark the fd as non-blocking, then continue write to the fd until write return -1.

I think since disk I/O is slow, when write buffers in OS is nearly full, the write system call will return -1, and the errno should be EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

But I ran the program for about several minutes and I repeated running the program serveral times, the write system call didn't returned -1 even once! Why? 
Here's the code:

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char    buf[4096];

int
main(void)
{
        int nwrite;

        int fd = open("a.txt", O_RDWR);
        if(fd<0){
            printf("fd<0\n");
            return 0;
        }
        int  i;
        for(i = 0; i<sizeof(buf); i++)
            buf[i] = i*2;

        set_fl(fd, O_NONBLOCK); /* set nonblocking */

        while (1) {
                nwrite = write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
                if (nwrite < 0) {
                    printf("write returned:%d, errno=%d\n", nwrite, errno);
                    return 0;
                }
        }

        clr_fl(STDOUT_FILENO, O_NONBLOCK);      /* clear nonblocking */

        exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Disk I/O is non-blocking by definition.  Same with `select()` and relations; a file descriptor for a disk file is always non-blocking (for read or write).

Comment: File IO is non blocking, because it goes to the file system and the page cache. So a given `write` does not correspond to some physical disk write.

Comment: If you want to see some blocking potential, try it on a large file on a  networked drive.

Comment: Why do expect this to happen? The man-page for POSIX `write` is quite explicit. From its "***ERRORS***" section: "*`EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` The file descriptor is for a socket, is marked `O_NONBLOCK`, and write would block.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `O_NONBLOCK` flag is primarily meaningful for file descriptors representing streams (e.g, pipes, sockets, and character devices), where it prevents read and write operations from blocking when there is no data waiting to read, or buffers are too full to write anything more at the moment. It has no effect on file descriptors opened to regular files; disk I/O delays are essentially ignored by the system.

If you want to do asynchronous I/O to files, you may want to take a look at [the POSIX AIO interface](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Asynchronous-I_002fO.html). Be warned that it's rather hairy and infrequently used, though.